# Should I get a PO box for a will / transfer on death deed?

Tags: texas, wills

I'm to be a beneficiary on a will for my father and I was asked for my address. The address I provided is in an apartment complex. Maybe I'll be in that same apartment complex when my father passes or maybe I won't be but given the uncertainty as to where I'll be I'm wondering if it might not bad idea to have a PO Box that I can keep between moves.

Can I even do that? Or can I pencil in my email address instead of my home address?

Comment: I'm not sure that a PO box is always accepted as identity. But your actual residence history is traceable. Are you saying you won't be aware that your father has passed?

Comment: @WeatherVane USPS [requires proof of identity and address](https://faq.usps.com/s/article/Acceptable-Form-of-Identification) to open a PO Box. It's likely more traceable than renting a house, I don't think I've ever been asked for photo ID to rent.

Comment: Practically everyone is uncertain about their future address, people move all the time during their lives. Do you think they all get PO boxes for this reason?

Comment: A consideration with email addresses is whether you'll still have the same one.  I lost an ISP-provided email address with no notice when they proved unable to connect my new house.  Since then I've got my own domain; registration and hosting aren't expensive but if I had no money at all I'd lose those. Even something like gmail or hotmail could still be lost, to identity theft for example.

Comment: THere's nothing wrong with ading more contact information - noone would bat an eye at email, cellphone, residential address.  Adding any gamer handle or @youtube or instagram or Stackexhange username might be a bit odd, but consider someone will be trying to find you in the future.  Best make that task as easy as possible for them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The address given is assumed to be the one you had at the time.

Even if that is not your current address upon your father's death, it still serves an important purpose: It allows you to be distinguished from other people with the same name or a similar name who did not live at that address at that point in time.

At death, someone will probably rely upon your father's address book or phone contacts to reach you (or maybe your most recent Christmas card), not the one listed in a will or a deed that is many years old.

There is no need for a P.O. Box.

> Or can I pencil in my email address instead of my home address?

Don't do it. This could come across as fraudulent conduct.

Comment: I agree with your last statement. I don't see a problem with keeping a _separate_ piece of paper along with the will listing current contact info.

Comment: Why would providing a correct and valid email address come across as fraudulent?

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate Because it is writing on a written instrument by a person who didn't sign it.

Comment: It's a bit unclear, but the OP may simply be using "pencil it in" as colloquial for providing their email address as opposed to a mailing address.  They may not be using that phrase literally.  Or they may... hard to tell.

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate - I meant to say "can I [have my Dad] pencil in my email address". ie. scratch out what it says and replace the verbiage with whatever he pleases. That said, I suppose it's a moot point, now, as I got the answer I sought.